# Equivalent of Background to run after scenarios

Tags: specflow, gherkin

I'm new to SpecFlow, and am setting up a number of test features/scenarios that are for authenticated users of different role types.  I'm doing this via browser automation with Coypu.

So I have a Background step in the feature to set up the log in of a user in that role type.

```
Background:
    Given I am logged in as a ...some role I'm interested in...
```

After each scenario in the feature, I want to log the user out again (otherwise the log in step in the Background won't work for the next scenario -- I'm keeping the same Coypu browser instance open in between tests).

I found the `[AfterScenario]` annotation that I could use, but as this is scoped across all scenarios in all features (as far as I understand...) it would affect scenarios say for unauthenticated users.

I could scope the `[AfterScenario]` with `[Scope(Feature="Some Feature")]` I believe, but I'm anticipating having to log in/out before and after a whole number of features that I'm testing, and I'm not keen on specifying all of these with a bunch of magic strings.

So I'm wondering if there's something I can put in the Feature file, kind of the equivalent of Background but to run *after* each scenario in that feature.  (Or alternatively, maybe the way I'm logging in/out for each scenario is not the best way to go about things?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no "Postground" feature in specflow however you can achieve something similar with [tags filtering](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks).

In most of our projects we are using tags to mark scenarios which have specific setup/teardown logic. 
Then we are using the BeforeScenario/AfterScenario hooks to execute the logic:

```
[BeforeScenario("authentication")]
public void BeforeAuthenticationScenario()
{
    //...
}    

[AfterScenario("authentication")]
public void AfterAuthenticationScenario()
{
    //...
}
```

And you can tag individual scenarios or whole features:

```
@authentication
Feature: Some feature requires authentication

@authentication
Scenario: Some scenario requires authentication
```

So in your code you will only have one magic string "authentication" and in your features you can apply the custom logic declaratively with the tag.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good way to go.  Just out of your interest, in your opinion, would something like "Postground" be a useful feature, or do you think there's a reason why it isn't present?

Comment: A haven't really thought about it but until you can do it from code with tags it's not huge problem. There is an ongoing discussion for a new feature to SpecFlow to support arbitrary steps which are built up from other steps, if it gets into with that you can also group post and preconditions for scenarios.